# How do I find out whether my UIActivityIndicatorView is working if the page loads too quickly for it to show up in the first place?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview, uiactivityindicatorview

I've set a delegate method that starts animating a `UIActivityIndicatorView` when a `UIWebView` starts loading and stops animating it when the `UIWebView` stops loading.  NSLogging shows that both delegate methods are being called (i.e., `webViewDidStartLoading` and `webViewDidFinishLoading`).

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
//start animating
[self.indicator startAnimating];
}

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
//finish animating
[self.indicator stopAnimating];
}
```

The problem is that the page finishes loading before the `UIActivityIndicatorView` shows up.  This means that either a) everything is working fine and my connection is quick enough that the `UIActivityIndicatorView` doesn't need to show up or b) not everything is working fine.

But how do I tell whether it's a) or b)?  Is there a way to slow down my connection artificially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would comment out your call to stopAnimating and see if your activity indicator view is still spinning. If it is then you know its your request that is super quick.

Or change the URL to load a webpage that you know takes a long time to load and see if you notice any difference.

Comment: Of course, now my problem is that, having commented out the call to stopAnimating, I see that the activity indicator view never started spinning.  So now I have to figure out why....

Answer (score 2):

Tunnel the traffic through a slow proxy, so you will have time to see if the indicator shows up.

One way to do that would be to install [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/), which has a throttling feature. (And is very convienient for other http-network debugging as well).

The equivalent tool on Windows is [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

Comment: +1 for recommending Charles - that tool is IMHO mandatory for all iOS developers working on server fed apps.

Comment: Thanks for this, though now there's yet another item on my list of Important Things I Have to Learn That I Don't Understand What the Heck They Are Yet....  :)

Answer (score 1):

In my app I simply didn't turn off/stop the activity indicator when loading was done and that showed me it was working then I went back and put in the stop.  So if it was replacing a button it will still be showing or if it was in an alertview it will still be up on screen.